# laravel putFileAs path error

Tags: php, laravel

I use the putFileAs method on the Storage facade to upload my photos.

```
        $gallery = $request->file('feature_image');
        Storage::putFileAs(
            'just_for_test_putfileas', $gallery, time().'.'. $request->file('feature_image')->getClientOriginalExtension()
        );
```

it works great and default putFileAs dir is **"storage/app"**
and will put my file in this direction **"storage/app/just_for_test_putfileas"**

when I use ../ in dir to put the file in some other direction it cause an error "whoops, it seems there is something wrong"
this block of code cause error

```
            $gallery = $request->file('feature_image');
            Storage::putFileAs(
              '../just_for_test_putfileas', $gallery, time().'.'. $request->file('feature_image')->getClientOriginalExtension()
        );
```

Comment: see the stackTrace of error, enable your debug first

Comment: debug is true in env . but debug mode set off !

Comment: Don't use `..` in an upload feature. It smells like path traversal attack, even if there might not be one in your case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you use the `Storage` facade without specifying a disk, it will use the default disk which is usually the `local` disk. This disk is rooted/jailed to the */storage/app/* directory and you cannot escape it.

See your settings in *config/filesystem.php*:

```
'disks' => [
    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],
```

If you want to be able to read and write files using Laravel's filesystem functionality to a different folder, you can create a new *disk* and jail it to another location:

```
'disks' => [
    'my-disk' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path(),
    ],
```

In my example above I have created a new *disk* jailed to the */storage/* path, which is the path above */storage/app/*. You can then use your disk with the `Storage` facade like this:

```
Storage::disk('my-disk')->putFileAs(...);
```